# How to find most common element in a list of list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, count, python-2.7

I understand

```
a = max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
```

will derive most common element in a list

but how do you derive most common element in a list of list without using helper function?

For example

```
lst = [['1','2','3','4'],['1','1','1','1'],['1','2','3','4']]
```

The output should equal `1`.

When I try `a = max(set(lst), key=lst.count)`

it writes `builtins.TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: what would be your expected output for : `[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1', '1', '2', '2'], ['2', '2', '3', '4']]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "helper function"? Your definition seems to include `Counter`, but excludes `max` and `set`. You'd be better thinking about avoiding O(N^2) behavior (like in your `max(set(lst), key=list.count)`) than using the standard library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways, but I wanted to let you know that there are some nice tools for that kind of things in the standard modules, e.g. [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [1]: lst = [['1','2','3','4'],['1','1','1','1'],['1','2','3','4']]
In [2]: from collections import Counter
In [3]: from operator import itemgetter
In [4]: max((Counter(l).most_common(1)[0] for l in lst), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
Out[4]: '1'
```

Or, you could (kinda) employ your current solution for each of the sublists:

```
In [5]: max(((max(set(l), key=l.count), l) for l in lst),
   ...: key=lambda x: x[1].count(x[0]))[0]
Out[5]: '1'
```

Comment: I really thank you for the codes, but do you have any other function that does not require itemgetter nor counter? So what I mean by that is just simple python programming which does not require any from statement nor import statement

Comment: Good Python code makes use of the excellent modules already available. Is there any reason you'd want to avoid built-in modules? Is this homework?

Comment: No, I would say its a part of homework to shorten a function without using too many if-statements, its an introduction of python course.

Comment: @EricJung Well, I added another example that partly uses the code you posted, but the first version seems better to me.

Answer (score 4):

Just flatten your `list of list`, and use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) on it. Then use `Counter.most_common()` method to get a `list` of `tuple` of elements with their count of occurrence from highest to lowest: -

```
>>> lst = [['1','2','3','4'],['1','1','1','1'],['1','2','3','4']]
>>> flattened_list = [elem for sublist in lst for elem in sublist]  
>>> flattened_list
['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4']
>>>
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> counter = Counter(flattened_list)
>>> counter.most_common()
[('1', 6), ('3', 2), ('2', 2), ('4', 2)]
>>>
>>> counter.most_common(1)
('1', 6)
```

Or, you can use your method to get most common element from the `flatten` list.

```
>>> max(set(flattened_list), key=flattened_list.count)
'1'
```

---

You can also flatten your list like this: -

```
>>> sum(lst, [])
['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

---

So, **as a one-liner,** you can do it like this: -

```
>>> lst = [['1','2','3','4'],['1','1','1','1'],['1','2','3','4']]

>>> max(set(sum(lst, [])), key=sum(lst, []).count)
'1'
```

Of course, the last one creates two lists, with same content.

Comment: `most_common` takes the number of items as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You have to flattern your list (with `chain(*lst)`), then count entry of each element of your list with `Counter(chain(*lst).most_common())` and sort the result.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

lst = [['1','2','3','4'],['1','1','1','1'],['1','2','3','4']]
sorted(Counter(chain(*lst)).most_common())[0][0]
```

Comment: Try to provide a comment or explanation as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Counter` to find the most common element, and `chain` to iterate through the elements of the list of lists:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

print Counter(val for val in chain.from_iterable(lst)).most_common(1)
```